# javascript command line editor in firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

[image]

Where can i find this command line editor of the new inspector in firefox? Is there any add-ons or settings to show this button/functionality in the new inspector? thanks in advance! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Just press F12 on the webpage. If you want the debugger as shown in the picture, you can install the addon firebug.

Comment: i know what firebug is, and i have been using it until now. what i just want to know is how to display the command line editor in the new firefox inspector.

Comment: @claire Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: i installed https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/console-sidebar/ to have a textarea like console.. :)